# How convert Angularjs code to Ajax or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have a angularjs code about 300 lines. I want to convert this code to jquery or Ajax.

The angularjs code is about weather report.

There is controllers, directives and filters.

I do not know How to cenvert or where to start to convert them to jquery/ajax

simple code, I have as an example:

```
module.directive("weatheroverview",function(){
  return{
   restrict:"E",
   scope:{
   datatime:"=",
   temp:"=",
   wind:"="
  },
  templateUrl:"view/weatherReport.html"
}
})
```

and so on.

how can I deal with that to convert them to ajax or jquery ?
should I build the directive elements with html ?
any resources for that?

thanks

Comment: There is no direct equivalent of this in JS/jQuery. Angular is an MVC framework. To replicate directives in Angular you'd need to recreate all the functionality in that part of the framework.

Comment: is there any resources to learn from them.
I know can code with js, but do not know where to start here. 

do you mean that I need to understand the whole angularjs code and recreate it from the beginning with ajax or jquery?

Comment: Why go to all that trouble? Its going to be messy and at the end of the day, you're trying to reinvent a wheel. Otherwise, you'll need to approach this thinking about how you'd do it without ever seeing the angular part

Comment: ok, I understand. I will then create the app from zero.